# How to run espresso tests with spoon with a specific build variant

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, ui-automation, android-espresso, spoon

I have written test cases using espresso and using spoon to run the test cases using command gradlew spoon

I have 4 different build variant in my android studio and want to run the test with a specific build variant.

But the spoon always starts the test with one of the build variant only

How can I pass the name of the build variant to conduct test on?

Comment: are you referring to buildTypes like debug, release and want to run the tests on one of those?

Comment: @source.rar  yes , I am referring to the buildTypes like Test app, productionapp, debug;etc

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `testBuildType` in the `defaultConfig` section to the buildType (`debug` / `staging` / `release`) that you want to run the tests with.

Reference - https://sites.google.com/a/android.com/tools/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Basics-and-Configuration